# Right procedure to transition beta app user's to release version

Tags: ios, mobile, ios8, testflight, beta

We are uploading our iOS Application to TestFlight for Beta testing. We are expecting a large number of people to get involved in this testing process.

I wanted to know what is the right procedure to transition all these user's to final release version of the app when it gets released in the AppStore?

Will the current Beta user's get update notification from the AppStore? or should be manually notify all the user's through mail or some other means, then they manually reinstall the app?

Any information on this will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

TestFlight builds will work on your tester's devices for 60 days, starting on the day it is released to testers (as described near the bottom [of this Apple TestFlight overview page](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/)).

Your testers can update their copy of your app to the Store version any time you release it on the app store, or their TestFlight versions will expire and they'll still have to go to the store to update and get their apps to work again.